# How to check whether a query is directed to node 1 or node 2 in postgres cluster configured with pgpool?

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I have configured pgpool with 2 nodes Postgres in replication mode. I would like to check the functionality of load balancing. So, I want to know if there is a way to check which query is redirected to which node in Pgpool -II. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set "log_per_node_statement" parameter "on". it print the logs for each DB node separately.

http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-config-logging.html